# jquery only be able to select current page records

Tags: jquery

I am using watable jQuery plugin. I am showing 25 records per page and there are total 10 pages. When I select all, it select all the records (from all 10 pages). I only want to select only current page record.

I am trying this:

```
var table = $('#tbl_questions').waTable();
var p = table.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you cannot access the currently shown page index since it's kept in a private variable.

A workaround is to intercept the pageChanged event and store the page index somewhere else (for simplicity's sake, let's use the global var `currentPage` here):

```
.WATable({

...

  pageChanged: function(data) {
    window.currentPage = data.page;
  },

...

});
```

Then I would do this:

```
var columnsInOrder = table.getData(false, true);
var pagesize = table.option("pageSize");
var shownRows = columnsInOrder.rows.slice( (currentPage - 1) * pagesize , currentPage * pagesize  );
```